# Return an object only when the method inside it is done

Tags: java, parse-platform, return

I'm using Parse.com as my backend and want to create a method that returns the queried object's columns as a Bundle. I'm having problems with the return though, how can I postpone the return until the query is done? I would like to put it in the done method of the query, but that's not allowed since its a void method. Here's my code:

```
public static Bundle queryForExtras() {

    final Bundle extras = new Bundle();

    ParseQuery<Song> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Song.class).fromPin(PIN_LABEL_SONG);
    query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<Song>() {
        @Override
        public void done(final Song song, ParseException e) {

            if (e == null) {
                extras.putString(COLUMN_SONGNAME, song.getSongname());
                extras.putString(COLUMN_LYRICS, song.getLyrics());

                // I WANT TO RETURN EXTRAS HERE

            } else {
                // Something went wrong
            }
        }
    });

    return extras;
}
```

How can I achieve the behaviour that I want?

Comment: Which Java Version do you use?

Comment: Don't return. Instead call a function :). 

     // I WANT TO RETURN HERE
     doSomething(extras);

Comment: Can you return a `java.util.concurrent.Future<Bundle>`?

Answer (score 4):

As `getFirstInBackground` obviously is executed in the background, you cannot directly return a value for the method `queryForExtras`. If you want to use `getFirstInBackground`, you have to create some kind of listener that is called once you received the bundle.

Yet the easiest way would be to use the [`getFirst`](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQuery.html#getFirst()) method that does not run in the background. So you can directly access the result in `queryForExtras`:

```
public static Bundle queryForExtras() {
    ParseQuery<Song> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Song.class).fromPin(PIN_LABEL_SONG);
    Song song = query.getFirst();

    final Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putString(COLUMN_SONGNAME, song.getSongname());
    extras.putString(COLUMN_LYRICS, song.getLyrics());
    return extras;
}
```